# How to add a GridView Column on code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I'm trying to add a column to a GridView, in ASP.NET 2.0

```
gridViewPoco.Columns.Add(...)
```

However, i cant find the right option. I'd like equivalents to the following:

```
<asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For example;

```
protected void Btn_AddCol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
    tf.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewLabelTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, "Col1", "Int32");
    tf.ItemTemplate = new GridViewLabelTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "Col1", "Int32");
    MyGridView.Columns.Add(tf);
}
```

- Define new [`TemplateField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx)
- Set the column header name (`Col1`) and type (`Int32`)
- Set the column value type (`Int32`)
- Add this field to your `Gridview`

Comment: Thanks for this, I had the same problem in one program some time ago. Hey, can you with this problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708957/c-sharp-metro-xaml-designing-the-page-for-any-of-the-screen

Comment: Why do i get an error like 'The type or namespace GridViewLabelTemplate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) when I try your code?

Comment: @KorayDurudogan Check: http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3609991/Dynamic-Template-Columns-in-the-ASPNET-20-GridView-Control.htm

Answer (score 5):

[Soner's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6017823/259014) is great for adding columns to the end of the Gridview. If, however, you find yourself needing to add columns to the middle of the GridView, you'll need to take a slightly different path (using the `MyGridView.Columns.Insert()` function):

```
  protected void Btn_AddCol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
    tf.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewLabelTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, "Col1", "Int32");
    tf.ItemTemplate = new GridViewLabelTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "Col1", "Int32");
    MyGridView.Columns.Insert(2, tf); //the 2 makes it go into the third column -- zero-based indexing ftw
    }
```