# how to bind one dimensional string array result to datagrid column header

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a query as follows, which returns the list of server names and component names

```
string match = "TEST"

var headerArray = from a in this.db.Servers
                 where a.ServerID.Contains(match)
                 join b in this.db.Components
                        on a.ServerID equals b.ServerID into g
                select new
                {
                    a.ServerID,
                    Components = g.Select(x => x.Name), 
                };

List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (var server in headerArray)
{
    result.Add(server.ServerID);

    foreach (var componentName in server.Components)
        result.Add(componentName);
}

string[] header = result.ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

```
datagrid1.ItemsSource = header.ToList();
```

header stores the list of servernames in the form of array. how to bind this result to the datagrid column ?

Comment: WinForms, Web, WPF? Why are you binding array to grid? Maybe simple list box will do the job?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention. it is WPF

Comment: I want to bind it because I have to create a dynamic matrix kind grid.

Comment: Why not just use the Server name as one of the fields? Assuming you are creating a `Server` object of some sort.

Comment: When i abind to the datagrid, I get the count of each servername as result with the header Length

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind gridview header columns.
You need to create a loop with string[] header and add columns dynamically.

you can go through the below url for how to add columns dynamically in gridview

[How to add a GridView Column on code-behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017670/how-to-add-a-gridview-column-on-code-behind)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13461/how-to-create-columns-dynamically-in-a-grid-view